# Does the phrase “so long as” have a negative sense?

Tags: conjunctions, negation, syntactic-analysis

Can I use *neither . . . nor* following the phrase *so long as*?

I read this sentence in an article:

> When I was in college a Marwari friend of mine told me that her parents would be totally open to her marrying anyone she wanted **so long as** that person was neither A nor B.

(Here A and B are two ethnicities)

Comment: So long as you withhold from us an actual specimen sentence, neither shall you receive reasonable answers nor useful advice. And you haven't shown any research or theories,  which makes this General Reference and Proofreading, both of which are Off Topic.

Comment: Title is misleading. "That fish is *as long as* my arm." is a completely different sense than the one he's asking about because it uses *as* instead of *so*.

Answer (score 2):

*As long as* can have a negative sense in a given context as well as a positive one in another context. So, the sense is based on the context. The plain *as long as* does not have neither positive nor negative connotations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use *neither . . . nor* with *so long as*.

*So long as* simply means *provided that*, or to put it another way, *under the condition that* — which can be followed by a positive or negative condition.